# Prepopulated stored data in iOS4

Tags: core-data, ios4, datastore

I work with iPhone iOS 4.3.

In my project I need a read-only, repopulated table of data (say a table with 20 rows and 20 fields).

This data has to be fetched by key on the row.

What is better approach? CoreData Archives, SQLite, or other? And how can I prepare and store this table?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by `20 fields`?

Comment: As in a database table: 20 rows and 20 columns.

Answer (score 1):

I would use core data for that. Drawback: You have to write a program (Desktop or iOS) to populate the persistent store.

How to use a pre-populated store, you should have a look into the Recipes sample code at apple's.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach would be to use an NSArray of NSDictionary objects and then save the array to disk as a plist. Include the plist in your build and then open it read only from the app bundle at runtime.

Each "row" would be the element index of the array which would return a dictionary object wherein each "column" would be a key-value pair.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this 2 different ways:

1. Saved all my data as dictionaries in a plist, then deserialized everything and loaded it into the app during startup
2. Created a program during development that populates the Core Data db. Save that db to the app bundle, then copy the db during app startup into the Documents folder for use as the Persistent Store

Both options are relatively easy, and if your initial data requirements get very large, it's also proven to be the most performant for me.