# Advices to store pre-populated data (image + text) for an iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, plist

I have built a recipe app for iOS and recently lost all my code thanks to a defective SSD drive and my astonishing stupidity not backing anything up. I learnt my lesson but instead of trying to build the same app again, I'd like to be a bit smarter this time.

The problem I always had was that adding new recipes was a huge pain because of the way they were stored: I named each picture "recipe_X.png" and I had a text file containing a bunch of comma separated lines with the following format "title, subtitle, quantity1, ingredient1, quantity2, ingredient2...".
I would then run a while loop from 1 to X and read the recipe information and load the image.

This worked fine but adding 10 new recipes would take me hours because I would need to fill all the data, resize all the images, rename them and then test each recipe to make sure names weren't too long. I would sometimes miss a line when entering data and everything would be screwed up. I also localized my app which would just multiple the time spent.

I wonder what is a better way to store the data knowing that it is read-only, the data size is relatively small and my main concern is the ease to pre-populate data. Core DB seems great but not the easiest to pre-populate data.

I like the suggestion from [techzen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/190807/techzen) but I would love an example about how to save an NSArray as a static file:
[Prepopulated stored data in iOS4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783283/prepopulated-stored-data-in-ios4/6800898#6800898)

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: After reading the answer you linked, I started to google.  I typed "plist nsa" and Google was autocompleting it to "plist nsarray example", and the first result for that google search was: [How to read data structure from .plist file into NSArray](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/749504/how-to-read-data-structure-from-plist-file-into-nsarray)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into the `NSCoding` protocol. Considering UIImage conforms to this protocol, you could create a model class with properties for image, title, subtitle, etc. that conforms to `NSCoding`. Add instances of this object to an `NSArray`, then call:

```
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:theArray toFile:someFilePath];
```